# Sending Email Content in HTML

Tags: java, spring, email

I have to send an email having all content in html that can be displayed in email as a HTML. I am able to send the email with `JavaMailSenderImpl` of Spring Framework with `SimpleMailMessage` but the email I send is displayed in plain html text like following

```
<html><body><h1>Hello</h1></body></html>
```

and not in form of HTML page.

Please tell the way how can i send it as HTML and how it can be displayed in form of HTML.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you are using java mail directly, you need to set the content type to html using the [setContent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setContent%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) method.
`MimeMessage.setContent("<html> <body><h1>Hello </h1> </body></html>", "text/html");`

Or if you are using Spring framework's [MimeMessageHelper](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/spring/spring-3.0.5/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html) you can use [MimeMessageHelper.setText(emailContent,true)](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/spring/spring-3.0.5/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html#setText%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method. The boolean `true` flag indicates html content. For instance:

```
    mimeMessageHelper.setTo("some@someone");
    mimeMessageHelper.setReplyTo("some@someone");
    mimeMessageHelper.setFrom("some@someone");
    mimeMessageHelper.setSubject("someSubject");
    mimeMessageHelper.setText("<html> <body><h1>Hello </h1> </body></html>",true);
```

Comment: : Thanks for your help. Now i able to send email as an html with the the help of mime message of spring..Cheers :)

Comment: How can I send both text and html?