# Thymeleaf Content-Type is being ignored in HTML Email (not rendered as HTML)

Tags: html, email, thymeleaf

I'm developing a RESTful API with Spring Boot as backend and an Angular 9 frontend. Upon user registration, a verification email is sent, in which the user needs to click on a link to verify their account. Functionally, all is set and working. However, the HTML is never rendered despite having Content-Type set to 'text/html' and charset to UTF-8. I'm using Thymeleaf to generate the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>TooManyThoughts</header>
    <section>
        <p th:text="#{registration.mail.greeting(${#messages.msg('mail.greeting.title.' + user.personalData.title.representation, user.personalData.firstName, user.personalData.lastName)})}"></p>
        <p th:text="#{registration.mail.preamble}"></p>
        <p>
            <a th:text="#{registration.mail.link}"
                 th:href="@{http://localhost:8081/auth/register/email/verify/{id}/{key}(id = ${user.id}, key = ${user.emailValidationKey}, send='auth,login', verified='email')}"></a>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span th:text="#{registration.mail.clue01(${user.credentials.username})}"></span>
            <span th:text="#{registration.mail.clue02}"></span>
        </p>
        <p th:text="#{registration.mail.catchphrase}"></p>
        <p th:text="#{registration.mail.goodbye}"></p>
        <p>
            <span th:text="#{registration.mail.signature01}"></span>
            <br>
            <span th:text="#{registration.mail.signature02}"></span>
        </p>
    </section>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

At the time of writing, all frameworks used are in their latest versions. Currently, I'm sending the email to my personal gmail account. When googling the issue, I've found some rendering issues with gmail, but they've all been old and from around 2011 or so. The only other posts and entries I could find were about setting Content-Type and charset properly, which in my opinion I've done.

I'm kinda stuck here since two days with what I believe should be a very basic issue, so any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: At first glance, your Thymeleaf template looks good. Can you show us the code which sets the content type and charset - i.e. the relevant `javax.mail.Message` statements? And in case it solves the issue, don't use `message.setText()`. Only use `message.setContent()`.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you very much for your reply. I'm gonna edit my question to add the code, but I can't do it before tomorrow morning. What I do know is that I use Spring's MimeMessagePreparator and MimeMessageHelper and I pass the charset to the constructor of the latter. I'll have a look at it tomorrow and then I will post it. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks to your hint on using `getContent` instead of `getText`, I was able to figure it out (s. answer). Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Andrew's hint on using `setContent()` instead of `setText()` for `javax.mail.Message`, I realized that I've never actually set the content type of my email anywhere in the code. I'm not using `javax.mail` but `springframework.mail.javamail`, so I had to look for a solution and I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652055/sending-email-content-in-html). The working code now looks like this:

```
public EmailVerificationModel sendMail(final EmailVerificationModel model) {
    final MimeMessagePreparator msgPreparator = mimeMessage -> {
        final MimeMessageHelper msgHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, "UTF-8");
        msgHelper.setFrom("petesideburner@gmail.com");
        msgHelper.setTo(model.getCredentials().getEmail());
        msgHelper.setSubject(this.mailBuilder.subject(model));
        msgHelper.setText(this.mailBuilder.build(model), true);
    };
    this.mailSender.send(msgPreparator);
    return this.verificationMailSent(model);
}
```

All that I had to do was to pass `true` as 2nd argument to Spring's `MimeMessageHelper.setText()` method. The hidden quirks of method signatures. Personally, I prefer more distinct names for methods and variables, and so for better readability of my code I've changed it to:

```
public EmailVerificationModel sendHtmlMail(final EmailVerificationModel model) {
    final boolean html = true;
    final MimeMessagePreparator msgPreparator = mimeMessage -> {
        [...]
        msgHelper.setText(this.mailBuilder.build(model), html);
    };
    this.mailSender.send(msgPreparator);
    return this.verificationMailSent(model);
}
```